# HTML elements selection visually uneven, vertical lines appearing

Tags: html, css

[image: The small (probably 1px) lines around the latter three elements]

On an HTML I'm working on, when a `<ul>` and its `<li>s` are visually selected in the browser with the cursor, some (the last three of the six) of the `<li>` elements show a white and a darker blue line next to them.
Why only some and why at all?
They are all in the same list, within the same `class` and without `id`s, all made using the same structure

```
   <li>
        <a href="link"><img src="image.png" style="height:21px; background-color:#ffffff"></a>
   </li>
```

Here is a jsFiddle, remember to select the result with your cursor.
http://jsfiddle.net/LjF99/1/

Comment: would be useful to see the full HTML and CSS, maybe in a jsfiddle

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, works fine for me in chrome.

Comment: @Doodlebunch thank you, I am in Safari, will check in other browsers too now

Comment: Added an update on the behaviour of other browsers. No answer is required anymore but it could be helpful to someone. Should the question be left this way, closed or deleted?

Comment: If you have found a solution / explanation to the problem you should provide it in an answer. Make sure to provide relevant information / code snippets directly in the answer and not just links. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is just a rendering glitch/difference;

The issue was originally found in Safari (7.0.5). Chrome, Firefox and iOS 7 iPad Safari have different ways of displaying selected HTML and elements are the same in those.